# Rounded JFrame -- is it possible?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, shapes

For some time now I was trying to make a `JFrame` with rounded borders however I was not able to.

I know the `setShape(java.awt.Shape)` method of a `JFrame` can be used to create `JFrame` with specific shape but I guess it is limited to the following:

`Rectangle2D` (sharp-edged)

`Ellipse2D`

`CubicCurve2D`

`QuadCurve2D`

`GeneralPath`

What I want to do is to create a `JFrame` with rounded corners.
How is that possible ?

*Note: My Eclipse IDE shows the setShape() method however the Java Doc online does not. Uhm... why ?*

Comment: Look here could be help [Create a rounded JFrame / ContentPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954566/create-a-rounded-jframe-contentpane)

Comment: @Smit The article on today.java.net uses `AWTUtilties` for setting the shape which has been replaced by `setShape()` :)

Comment: [notice for Java7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219111/cant-transparent-and-undecorated-jframe-in-jdk7-when-enabling-nimbus)

Comment: I do not want a circular JFrame, I want a rectangle with rounded corners

Comment: I do not want a circular JFrame == nobody talking about,  I want a rectangle with rounded corners == is possible

Comment: *"I want a rectangle with rounded corners"*  See **[`RoundRectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RoundRectangle2D.html)**.